# Como realizar una consulta de buscar a lambda en c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, lambda

Espero me puedan ayudar o mandarme link con ejemplos o donde pueda ver algo más similar a lo que busco.

Estoy tratando de hacer un expresión lambda del botón de buscar con la siguiente consulta:

```
select * 
from registros 
where Nombres like '%' + @valor + '%' or 
      paterno like '%' + @valor + '%' or 
      materno like '%' + @valor + '%'
```

Espero me puedan orientar.

Comment: eh... lei varias veces tu pregunta, y no entiendo nada de lo que queres hacer.. a que llamas un lambda? de paso, podrias poner mas contexto?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para eso debes usar **Linq**:

```
var lista = (from r in registros
             where r.Nombre.Contains(valor) ||
                   r.paterno.Contains(valor) ||
                   r.materno.Contains(valor)
             select r).ToList();
```

Aquí haces uso de **Linq** para realizar tu consulta orientada a objetos, y haces uso además de la **función Contains** para saber si **valor** esta contenida en las **propiedades Nombre**, **paterno** o **materno**.

Para usar **Linq** debes poner en los **usings**:

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: muchas gracias, igual estaba haciendo algunos arreglos pero me marca error en el nombre de la tabla.

Comment: ya lo solucione muchas gracias